# How can I recover moved jpg files

Tags: data-recovery, rm, mv, jpeg

On my ubuntu system I ran a command and moved all my jpg files to a single file by mistake

```
src_dir=$1
echo "src_dir: $src_dir"

for f in $src_dir/*; do
    if [ -f $f ]; then
        new_dir=$(date -r $f +"%b_%Y")
        if [ ! -d $new_dir ]; then
            mkdir $new_dir
        fi
        echo "File: $f "
        mv $f $src_dir/$new_dir
    fi
done
```

I tried recovering my jpg files using `recoverJpeg` and `scalpel`. These tools were able to recover the images which I deleted long back. However I did not recover any image which got moved using mv command.

I understand its a long shot but is there any way to get back the images?

Comment: No help now, but the `mv -t dir a b c d` format command prevents this issue. The target dir is checked to be a directory, and remaining names are sources: there is no file/directory ambiguity about the last argument.

Comment: Even without `-t` there is a way to make the command safer: `mv a b c d dir/`. The trailing slash is the key. If `dir` is a directory or a symlink to a directory then `dir/` will be resolved and the command will be able to proceed. Otherwise (including when `dir` does not exist) `dir/` will result in an error and the command will fail without moving anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `recoverJpeg` and `scalpel` can't find them, I'd say no.

However, once upon a time, those files existed simultaneously, so their data  occupied different places in the disk.  Moving files inside the same mount point should be nothing more that removing the old inode on the source folder, and creating a new inode on the destination folder, pointing to the same disk sectors that hold the data.  That's why it's almost instantaneous to move a huge file within the same mount point, no new data is written, only reused.  So, in theory, `mv`ing your files might (should?) not have erased the data. *However* when you `mv` a new file to a pre-existing file (i.e. dropping the first file's inode and creating a new one *with the same name* but pointing at another part of the disk), the sectors that hold the data of the first file are marked as free, and might be overwritten.  (Note that all this might not be entirely true, depending on your filesystem, but in my experience it usually is).

So when stuff like this happens it is crucial to mount the filesystem read-only, before using the forensic tools.  If they can't find anything, maybe the data is really gone.  If you have room for it, creating an image of the filesystem with `dd` might also help, as it "crystallizes" things for future forensic work.

Relatedly, adding these three lines to my `.profile` has saved my ass on many many occasions:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

Comment: Unclear whether the OP entered a 13-line command at the terminal (seems unlikely), or if it is in fact a script. In the latter case, aliases will not save you: aliases in the interactive shell are not passed to the script.

Comment: "these … has saved … on many many occasions" – Until you somehow find yourself in an environment without these aliases and fail spectacularly because you expect the tools to always ask and save you. Or maybe until you develop a habit to confirm again and again, and one day your muscle memory will win with your conscious mind.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  Observed a riff on that. Senior guy wanted to remove some executables from a remote server to force a remake. So he pulled back a list, and sent an `rm ... ` back. Unfortunately the server had an alias for `ls` which included the `-F` option, so all the executable names had come back marked with a `*`. So the `rm ...` saw wildcards and deleted most of the development system. Guy didn't understand what went wrong, so he "tested" it again on the back-up server.